# Replace nulls values in sql using select statement in mysql?

Tags: mysql, sql

Ho to do this?
What query can be written by using **select** statement where all nulls should be replaced with 123?

I know we can do this y using, 
    update tablename set fieldname = "123" where fieldname is null;

but can't do it using **select** statement.

Comment: update tablename set fieldname = "123" where fieldname is null;

Comment: I know this function, but how to do this replacement of null value using select statement ?

Answer (score 51, accepted):

You have a lot of options for substituting NULL values in MySQL:

[**`CASE`**](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/case.html)

```
select case 
    when fieldname is null then '123' 
    else fieldname end as fieldname 
from tablename
```

[**`COALESCE`**](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/comparison-operators.html)

```
select coalesce(fieldname, '123') as fieldname 
from tablename
```

[**`IFNULL`**](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/control-flow-functions.html)

```
select ifnull(fieldname, '123') as fieldname 
from tablename
```

Comment: yes, this is what i was looking for. thanks.
Can be also write a query by using the select statement, where we want all NULL values to be at last using Order By.

Comment: This answer is useful for other databases as well.  For example, both COALESCE and IFNULL are present in SQLite and work as expected.

Comment: Note: IFNULL is for MySql alone. If you are using MS Access or SQL Server, then you are looking for ISNULL, and if you are using Oracle then you are looking for NVL. Source: https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_isnull.asp

Comment: @Tyler Careful with blanket statements, there's http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEPEK_10.0.0/sqlref/src/tpc/db2z_bif_ifnull.html

Comment: If anyone else is using ScannerVision (i.e. probably me from the future), use COALESCE.

Answer (score 6):

There is a statement called IFNULL, which takes all the input values and returns the first non NULL value.

example:

```
select IFNULL(column, 1) FROM table;
```

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/control-flow-functions.html#function_ifnull

Comment: This answers the question, but it's important to note that IFNULL only takes two arguments.  COLAESCE (which is an MSSQL feature) takes an arbitrary number of input vales and returns the first non-null.

Answer (score 2):

I think you're looking for the IFNULL function
`IFNULL(field, 0)` will return a 0 when the field returns null

Answer (score 0):

An UPDATE statement is needed to update data in a table. You cannot use the SELECT statement to do so.

Comment: I think he wants to modify the output of the query, not the actual data.

Comment: Ah, seems I misunderstood the question then :-(

Comment: its ok Exupery. We have the answer from RedFilter

Answer (score 0):

```
select NVL(columnname, '#') as columnName from tableName
select NVL(email, '%') as email, NVL(city, '%') AS city FROM Account
```