# How to display database values in JFreeChart linechart

Tags: java, jfreechart

I have a question about a `JFreeChart` issue. I want to display a chart with a line from the values out of my database. This is the code I have now:

```
public void drawachart(){
    try{
        String sql= "select status,date from luggage";
        JDBCCategoryDataset dataset = new JDBCCategoryDataset(
            "jdbc:mysql://localhost/corendon", "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver", "root", "root");
        dataset.executeQuery(sql);
        JFreeChart chart = ChartFactory.createLineChart("chart","date", "status",
            dataset,PlotOrientation.VERTICAL,false,true,true);
        BarRenderer bar= null;
        bar = new BarRenderer();
        CategoryPlot plot =null;
        ChartFrame frame = new ChartFrame("shart", chart);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setSize(500, 500);
    }
    catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

After executing the code, it gives me a chart with no lines in it. Only a x and y axis. What should I do to get a line in the chart.

Comment: So is it working or not.Are you getting any error ?What is your question?

Comment: and the question is...... ?

Comment: After executing the code it gives me a chart with no lines in it. Only a x and y axis. What should i do to get a line in the chart.

Answer (score 1):

Try [`JDBCXYDataset`](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/data/jdbc/JDBCXYDataset.html), mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user:230513%20%5Bjfreechart%5D%20JDBCXYDataset). Because "the first column will be the x-axis," change your query to `"select date, status from luggage"`. `JDBCXYDataset` can detect a time series based on metadata, so `ChartFactory.createTimeSeriesChart()` may be a suitable choice.

Comment: I have tried, but i want the graph to select all the number 0s from my status column in the DB. I am getting a weird graph right now.

Comment: You might also need to check for `NULL`, for [example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9877657/230513).