# How to replace a column with null values in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

One of my columns in the table contains 'NULL' values and I would like to replace them with certain values.

I looked at this post: [Replace nulls values in sql using select statement?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9877533/replace-nulls-values-in-sql-using-select-statement) and followed the answer.

My sql statement:

```
Select ifnull(`option`, 'MCQ') as `option` 
from question_table
```

This statement returns me the columns there are already with 'MCQ', but the 'NULL' values are not replaced yet.

Need some guidance to change this.

Comment: Check your data, is the `option` value really NULL or 'NULL'?

Comment: Are you filtering out data with some where condition ? This should return the null values as 'MCQ'.

Comment: I am not filtering out data. If i use the search functionality and put "IS NULL", I am able to get all the data out that have option as NULL.

Comment: @lakesh . . . How do you know whether the values are changing or not?  Is that the entire query?  Can you edit your question and provide sample data and the results you are getting with your query?

Comment: I click the database again and search if there is any NULL options. It shows it to me.

Comment: The statement you are using performs merely a selection, it does not update any actual data in the database.

Comment: If you want to modify the data in the database then the statement you need is [`UPDATE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/update.html), not [`SELECT`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/select.html)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to *change* the data, you need an `update`:

```
update question_table
    set option = 'MCQ'
    where option is null;
```

A `select` statement does not change the database.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to update the table use [Gordon's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30870295/284240), but maybe you just want to return a replacement value for `NULL` in the `SELECT`, you can use [`COALESCE`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#function_coalesce):

```
SELECT COALESCE(`option`, 'MCQ') as `option` 
FROM question_table
```

This selects `MCQ` for every `option`-value that is `NULL`.

Another way is using `CASE`:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN `option` IS NULL THEN 'MCQ' ELSE `option` END as `option` 
FROM question_table
```

Comment: tried this as well. it just returned me the column of options with 'MCQ'

Comment: I wanted it to replace it.

Comment: @lakesh: if you want to update your table use `UPDATE`... of course.

Answer (score 0):

`'NULL'` is a string, [`NULL`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_%28SQL%29) is a special value that means "unknown/unavailable". They are totally different things.

MySQL function [`IFNULL()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/control-flow-functions.html#function_ifnull) handles `NULL` values (they cannot be compared using the regular comparison operators). You **can** use the regular comparison operators (`=`, `<>`) to work with strings, even when they are `'NULL'`.

If your query produces 'NULL' values in the result set it means the values in the database are not `NULL` but strings (`'NULL'`).

In this case the query you need is:

```
SELECT IF(`option` = 'NULL', 'MCQ', `option`) AS `option` 
FROM question_table
```